# TreeView in IOS rearrange following Subviews after adding or removing subviews from Scrollview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, treeview

I try to create an n-dimensional Treeview Control for an IOs application.
I use a UiViewController with a UIScrollView and have a custom UIView Class for the TreeNodes.
Now I want to collapse and Expand the Treenodes, but if i add or remove Subviews From the Scroll View i have to rearrange the other subviews.

This is the Tree:

[image]

If i collapse the second Node and remove the childnodes it looks like that:

[image]

Is there a way to realise something like that, without programatically rearrange the following Subviews?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already realized a lot of code?
Because I probably would use a tableview.

As datasource of the table you can use an array of dictionary; and in each dictionary you can store the rows informations like:

*row element*;// current element to display

*parent element*;//* to the parent element

*generation*; //NSInteger number of parents (you can use it to do the indentation)

so when you delete a row, you can search in all the datasource the items with that parent element, and substitute it with the parent of the deleted row (if exists); than decrement the generation for them, and recursively for all the children (until you will find no more children).

Of course, when populating the tableview you can easily use the generation number to make the indentation.

Comment: I do have realised a lot of code, i habe a "meta structure" ehich holds the data of my Objects an i use this stuckture to displa my data in different scenes (eg in a map, calendar, list) I also build the tree view out of the meta structure and if i expand or collapse an object, i be able to calculate wich nodes are displayed or not. The only problem with the UIScrollView is, that i have to rearrange all the following Subviews in a for each loop and this is not as performant as my code in Android, where the views rearranged themselfes. I will check the behaviour of a table View for my needs

Comment: well done, but really, for your case the best solution in iOS was the tableview... If you don't find a solution you can always use this...

https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/ratreeview

... good luck anyway :) and good coding

Comment: thanks, i will study this interesting project, and already build a solution based on a TableView. Much better and closer to my Android Project, where i used a Custom ListViewAdapter